# How can I Select an Element after appendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an empty div, like this:

```
<div class="albums"></div>
```

When user login in I call `getPhotos();` function, and this function add some data inside `albums` div, like this:

```
$('<div class="photo"><img class="photoimg" src="IMG" ></div>').appendTo($('.albums'));
```

adding data successfull.

I see images but I think jQuery doesnt see.

I cant select images.

```
$('.photoimg').click(function(){
        alert();
});
```

any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are dynamic elements. So you need to [delegate the events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Use event delegation this way:

```
$('.albums').on('click', '.photoimg', function() {
  // your code
});
```

Comment: at least fix the spelling when you copy

Comment: @madalinivascu Sure... Thanks! Ha ha... `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) like this

```js
$('<div class="photo"><img class="photoimg" src="IMG" ></div>').appendTo($('.albums'));

$('.albums').on('click', '.photoimg', function () {
  console.log(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="albums"></div>
```